# Contador regressivo em javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Galera estou com o seguinte código que é para fazer um countdown em cima de um cookie ele será redirecionado, mas ele nao esta imprimindo na pagina alguem consegue me ajudar

```
var tempo = new Number();
  // Tempo em segundos
  tempo = 300;

  function startCountdown(){

    // Se o tempo não for zerado
    if((tempo - 1) >= 0){

      // Pega a parte inteira dos minutos
      var min = parseInt(tempo/60);
      // Calcula os segundos restantes
      var seg = tempo%60;

      // Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...
      if(min < 10){
        min = "0"+min;
        min = min.substr(0, 2);
      }
      if(seg <=9){
        seg = "0"+seg;
      }

      // Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro
      horaImprimivel = '00:' + min + ':' + seg;
      //JQuery pra setar o valor
      $("#sessao").html(horaImprimivel);

      // Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo
      setTimeout('startCountdown()',1000);

      // diminui o tempo
      tempo--;

      // Quando o contador chegar a zero faz esta ação
    } else {
      window.open('../controllers/logout.php', '_self');
    }

  }

  // Chama a função ao carregar a tela
  startCountdown();
```

Comment: Fala parceiro beleza? especifique melhor sua pergunta, ficou meio confusa

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mLPzRR

Comment: Seja mais especifico com sua pergunto, e qual seu objetivo final?

Comment: coloque `<span id="sessao"></span>` no HTML da  pagina ou `<p id="sessao"></p>` ou `<div id="sessao"></div>` ou enfim <elementoHTML id="sessao"></elementoHTML>

Comment: Caso alguma resposta solucione seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/6985#6985

Answer (score 1):

> coloque um elemento HTML com o `id="sessao"` no codigo HTML da sua página exemplos: `<span id="sessao"></span>` ou `<p id="sessao"></p>` ou `<div id="sessao"></div>` ou enfim `<elementoHTML id="sessao"></elementoHTML>`

**A Biblioteca é requerida**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**

```
<script language="javascript">
var tempo = new Number();
  // Tempo em segundos
  tempo = 300;

  function startCountdown(){

    // Se o tempo não for zerado
    if((tempo - 1) >= 0){

      // Pega a parte inteira dos minutos
      var min = parseInt(tempo/60);
      // Calcula os segundos restantes
      var seg = tempo%60;

      // Formata o número menor que dez, ex: 08, 07, ...
      if(min < 10){
        min = "0"+min;
        min = min.substr(0, 2);
      }
      if(seg <=9){
        seg = "0"+seg;
      }

      // Cria a variável para formatar no estilo hora/cronômetro
      horaImprimivel = '00:' + min + ':' + seg;
      //JQuery pra setar o valor
      $("#sessao").html(horaImprimivel);

      // Define que a função será executada novamente em 1000ms = 1 segundo
      setTimeout('startCountdown()',1000);

      // diminui o tempo
      tempo--;

      // Quando o contador chegar a zero faz esta ação
    } else {
      window.open('../controllers/logout.php', '_self');
    }

  }

  // Chama a função ao carregar a tela
  startCountdown();
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
 <html>
 ......
 ......
 <body>
  ......
  ......
  <span id="sessao"></span>
  ......
  ......
 </body>
 </html>
```